# Impact of blocking subdirectory via robots.txt that belong to another website

Tags: robots.txt

I have hosting setup on hostgator which creates addon domains inside a subdirectory of the main site. So the structure is

```
public_html
    - main_site
        - main_site_folders
        - addon_site1
        - addon_site2
```

and so on. If I disallow addon_site1 and addon_site2 from robots.txt in main site will it stop search engines from indexing the addon sites? I am not able to find a direct answer to this, if somebody can point to me a document that explains this concept without ambiguity, it'll be appreciated.

Comment: May have to change my answer below - do you access your website by http://hostname/main_site ? or are you using a host header to partition main_site against another host?

Comment: main_site = main_site.com.
main_site/addon_site1 = addon_site1.com
main_site/addon_site2 = addon_site.com

These are very much independent websites, I'd host each of them in a different folder if that was possible but this is how it has been setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you block `/main_site/addon_site`, then robots would not go to `www.main_site.com/addon_site`. However, that wouldn't prevent them from going to `www.addon_site.com` directly.

If you want to prevent them from indexing `www.addon_site.com`, you'll need to put a robots.txt file in the `addon_site` folder:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

You need to clarify in your question what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
Disallow: /main_site/addon_site1
Disallow: /main_site/addon_site2
```

...assuming robots.txt is in your public_html directory.

If your site root is in /public_html/main_site (eg: http://example.com/ points to /public_html/main_site), you'd put robots.txt in /public_html/main_site with the following:

```
Disallow: /addon_site1
Disallow: /addon_site2
```